# PHP not catching AJAX variable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

**Thank you all so much for your help! I've begun to figure out where I went wrong. Stupid me was sending the data as an array instead of as a single string of the element ID.**

I've spent the past few days on Stack Overflow & other sources trying to find an answer to this problem. SO has a TON on this subject but none of the solutions have worked for me. I'm sure it's something ridiculously obvious.

I've excluded a lot of the code for readability & sake of minimalism. The project I'm working on is supposed to open a modal window & load in content from the database.

My problem is that PHP won't pick up the variable for the life of me. Literally everything else is working with the exception of this variable pulling through. My code pulls the div id and matches it in the php file. Or it is supposed to. When I try to echo the variable or $_POST nothing comes out. I've also tried using isset to test - it always comes out negative.

I've tried GET, POST - neither of which seem to be working for me.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

```
<div id="despair" class="cartoon" onclick="openEp(this.id)">
<p>content here</p>
</div>

<div id="friday" class="cartoon" onclick="openEp(this.id)">
<p>different content here</p>
</div>

<script>
function openEp(clikId) {
episode_name = clikId;

$.ajax({
 type: 'POST',
 url: 'cartoons.php',
 data: ({episode_name: episode_name}),
 success: function(data) {
  console.log('sent ' + episode_name);
 }
});
}
</script>
```

and for my cartoons.php file

```
<?php include 'connect.php';

$conn = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);

$episode_name = $_POST["episode_name"];
echo $_POST['episode_name'];

?>
```

Comment: try with `data: {episode_name: episode_name},` without the **()**

Comment: @HamzaAbdaoui — Why would that make a difference?

Comment: Is the request sent as JSON, or as form-encoded format? Probably the former, which is why it's not decoded into `$_POST`.

Comment: what Hamza said, if that doesnt work, look at the `request headers` and see what you are sending.  note: `element-id` is spoofable so make sure your data is sanitized server-side.

Comment: Using the network tab of your browser, you should debug whether the problem is within your JS or the PHP part, while I suspect the first option

Comment: @deceze — We can see the code. jQuery ajax, when passed a simple object like that, will form encode it.

Comment: @Quentin Fair enough, but I have given up trying to infer what jQuery will or won't do… :)

Comment: To repeat what @Nico said: open your browser's developer tools' network inspector and look at the actual HTTP request and response. That's the most straight forward way to get closer to the problem.

Comment: `this.id` give you the id you want? If yes, no need to do `episode_name = clikId;`, just `data: {'episode_name': clikId},` (I remove the () and add '', it shouldn't change the result but this is how I do by habit !), then if you do `console/log(data)` in your success JS you still get nothing?

Answer (score 4):

This is your success function:

> ```
> success: function(data) {
>   console.log('sent ' + episode_name);
> }
> ```

You are ignoring `data`.

If you want to output the response, then you need to write code to do it, e.g.:

```
success: function(data) {
  console.log(data);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Through outputting my data I realized I was sending something other than what I wanted. However, my PHP file still says that $_POST is empty. Is there something wrong with my PHP file as well?

Comment: Depends on what you are posting

Answer (score -2):

Try this. I am getting response. **html file**

```
<div id="despair" class="cartoon" onclick="openEp(this.id)">
    <p>content here</p>
</div>

<div id="friday" class="cartoon" onclick="openEp(this.id)">
    <p>different content here</p>
</div>

function openEp(clikId) {
    episode_name = clikId;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'cartoons.php',
        data: ({episode_name: episode_name}),
        success: function(data) {
        console.log('sent ' + episode_name);
        }
    });
}
```

**connect.php**

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
const DB_HOST = "localhost";
const DB_USERNAME = 'root'; 
const DB_PASSWORD = '';
const DB_DATABASE = '#dbname';
```

**cartoons.php**

```
<?php 
include 'connect.php';
$conn = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  // echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
} else {
  // echo "connected";
}

$episode_name = $_POST["episode_name"];
echo $_POST['episode_name'];
```

Comment: "Try" what exactly? What did you change?

Comment: Are you facing issue in LOCAL ? check database connected ?

Comment: Add error_reporting(E_ALL) at the top of connect.php. Then you will see the warning and notice errors

Answer (score -2):

Ok, try this way maybe this is how I use to work with Ajax :

```
<div id="despair" class="cartoon" onclick="openEp(this.id)">
    <p>content here</p>
</div>

<div id="friday" class="cartoon" onclick="openEp(this.id)">
    <p>different content here</p>
</div>

<script>
function openEp(clikId) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'cartoons.php',
        data: {episode_name: clikId}, // I did some change
        dataType : "JSON", // I add this
        // Now your success with some modification
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response.data)
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Your PHP :

```
<?php include 'connect.php';

$conn = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);

// You create an array you will use as result
$result = array();

// I add your data in the result array, the same way you can create $result['message'] and send back a success message or what you want
$result['data'] = $_POST["episode_name"];

// You send your array in JSON format as you wrote in your Ajax call
echo json_encode($result);

?>
```

Is it working with the JSON format?

Comment: Why people downvote and doesn't explain why?